# List all elements in a container

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I want to list all controls (buttons, datagrids, etc) in a container

This works but gives me a warning `1008: variable 'comp' has no type declaration.`

```
for (var i:int = 0;i<this.numElements;i++)
{
    var comp = this.getElementAt(i);
    trace(comp.id);
}
```

This is how I thought it should work but gives me a compiler error `1119: Access of possibly undefined property id through a reference with static type mx.core:IVisualElement.`

```
for (var i:int = 0;i<this.numElements;i++)
{
    var comp:IVisualElement = this.getElementAt(i);
    trace(comp.id);
}
```

In my head, when I get a compiler warning it's because I'm not doing something the way it is supposed to be.

Are there any alternatives to reference the id property? A method I'm missing even a whole different way iterate through all the controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type it as a `UIComponent`. Components will extend this class. (fl.controls components and mx.core components both extend a UIComponent class)

Comment: FYI - In Flex 4 casting as a UIComponent might not be what you want as GraphicElements like Rect or BitmapImage do not extend from UIComponent.

Comment: @Steven Those would be considered controls?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the definition of a "control" is.  In Flex 4 there are elements (IVisualElement) which are either UIComponent, GraphicElement, SpriteVisualElement, or UIMovieClip objects. UIComponent is the base class for components like Button, List, DataGrid, etc.  GraphicElement is the base class for purely visual shapes like Rect, Ellipse, Line, BitmapImage, etc.  SpriteVisualElement is the base class to support compile-time optimized FXG graphics.  UIMovieClip is the base class for components created with the Flex Component Kit for Flash.

Answer (score 2):

The IVisualElement interface does not declare a getter for 'id'. Assuming that all elements you are trying to retrieve are UIComponents you'll have to cast to UIComponent. Or better yet to IAdvancedStyleClient, which is the interface that declares the getter function for the 'id' property of UIComponent.

```
var comp:IAdvancedStyleClient = getElementAt(i) as IAdvancedStyleClient;
if (comp) trace(comp.id);
```

I test whether `comp` is not `null` here, just in case the component at position 'i' would in fact not implement IAdvancedStyleClient.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be another way of getting your elements?

```
for each(var comp:UIComponent in this)
trace(comp.id);
```